# DIfferent fragments for different orientation

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb

I have an Activity in a tablet app and I want to show different Fragments depending on the orientation. I figured the easiest way to do this was just to define two different layout XML files, one for landscape and one for portrait. In other words I have /layout/home.xml which looks like this:

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal">
  <fragment class="com.foo.app.Frag1" android:id="frag1"/>
  <fragment class="com.foo.app.Frag2" android:id="frag2"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And then in /layout-port/home.xml:

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical">
  <fragment class="com.foo.app.Frag2" android:id="frag2"/>
  <fragment class="com.foo.app.Frag3" android:id="frag3"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

When I run it, I can start in landscape and go to portrait, and everything is fine. However, when I go from portrait to landscape, the app crashes with a android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException with Resource ID equal to "frag3." That's right it's looking for Frag3 when going to landscape made, and there is no Frag3 in that mode. This happens during the Activity.onCreate stack, so before any of my code has any chance to make the app crash.

Are Fragments not supposed to work this way? Do I need to use a FragmentTransaction instead?

Comment: This is purely a guess, but it may be that the FragmentManager is saving/restoring the fragments in onPause/onCreate through the savedInstanceState bundle.  Try explicitly passing null to super.onCreate() and see if that resolves the crash.

Comment: Try calling `setRetainInstance(false);` in your fragments.

Comment: Can you provide a stacktrace?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say without seeing the code-  However, Resources.NotFoundException usually means you tried to look up an asset (think R.layout.xx, R.drawable.xx, etc) incorrectly.

That said, I tried writing a small app using your layout XML, and the compiler yelled at me for hardcoding strings as the ID's when I copied in your XML code to test it out.  Try switching the values of the android:id attribute to read like this:

android:id="android:id="@+id/frag1"

that might fix the issue.